# End of file <EOF> not defined in Scala grammar file

Tags: scala, grammar, antlr4

I am using Antlr V4 and grammar file to parse the entire code. The parser, lexer, baselistener are generated from the grammar file using Antlr jar. And then call the appropriate context to scan the entire file. 
e.g. For java, the context used is `compilationUnit`; for C++, the context is `translationunit`; for Javascript the context is `program` etc. These context keywords for different languages are defined in their respective grammar file, wherever EOF(End of file) is declared.

e.g.

```
compilationUnit :packageDeclaration? importDeclaration* typeDeclaration* EOF;
```

This is few lines in Java8.g4 file where EOF is declared under compilationUnit. So compilationUnit is the context that should be used to scan the entire java file. Similar is the situation for other languages.

But similar context finding isn't possible for scala language. As no EOF is defined in Scala.g4 file. I am referring to scala grammar file from following link.
https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/scala

All the grammar files for different languages that I use are from the same github page.

This anomaly in scala.g4 file leads to the question; is scala.g4 file not complete or erroneous? Or am I missing anything here?

Basic question is what's the context that should be used to scan entire scala file with the help of Antlr.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, these grammars are developed and supported by an open-source community, not by official language developers.

Of course, some grammars can be incomplete or written in different styles. If you want you can add EOF token to Scala grammar by yourself and make a pull request.

It's also possible to add EOF token programmatically to any rule.